# Replicate a VLOOKUP, using nested ifelse

Tags: r, nested

What is the operator for 'Equals' in the below question ?

```
S1$CountryNo <- ifelse(S1$Country = 'UNITED KINGDOM' , 1 , ifelse(S1$Country = 'FRANCE' , 2 , 3)
```

Comment: you need to use `==` instead of `=`

Comment: So simple ! Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a long list of counties you could also consider a lookup vector:

```
S1 <- data.frame(CountryNo = c("UNITED KINGDOM", "FRANCE", "DENMARK"))

# Lookup vector
lookup <- c("UNITED KINGDOM" = 1, "FRANCE" = 2)

# Replace known countries - unknown (DENMARK) will be NA
S1$CountryNo <- lookup[S1$CountryNo]

# Replace NA countries with 3
S1[is.na(S1$CountryNo), "CountryNo"] <- 3
```

Comment: Thank You, that would have been my next learning point !